# Mysql like query on two tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables user and author

user

```
    +---------+--------------+-----------+
    | user_id | first_name   | last_name |
    +---------+--------------+-----------+
    |    1    | Irene        | Appelbaum |
    |    2    | Leora        | Barel     |
    +---------+--------------+-----------+
```

author

```
   +-----------+------------+-------------+-----------+
   | author_id | first_name | middle_name | last_name | 
   +-----------+------------+-------------+-----------+
   |         1 | Gregory    | L           | Campbell  | 
   +-----------+------------+-------------+-----------+
```

my query is

```
select u.first_name,a.first_name 
from user u,authors a 
where  u.first_name like'%gre%' a.first_name like'%gre%';
```

but this query gives me result from both table

Comment: Well yes, that is because you select data from both tables using a cartesian join query (note the `,` in the `FROM` part of your query). Maybe you want to explain more detailed what it is you are looking for? Probably you are oooking for some other type of join, but we cannot _guess_ that. Reading the mysql ducumentation might be a good idea. It tells you everything about different join types.

Comment: Use `inner join` to merge the tables

Comment: And in the where clause..is it the `and` or the `or` condition that you want??

Comment: I got my solution using this query  SELECT first_name
FROM authors
WHERE first_name LIKE '%a%'
UNION ALL SELECT first_name
FROM user
WHERE first_name LIKE '%a%'
LIMIT 0 , 30

Answer (score 0):

its because you dont have id to relation for user and author table.

so from user table example Leora have Gregory for author.. like Irene have Gregory too for author..

you must defined relation for user and author table..

Im sorry my english is terrible :D

Answer (score 0):

May be you want something like this:

```
select u.first_name,a.first_name 
from user u inner join author a on u.user_id=a.author_id
where  u.first_name like'%gre%' or a.first_name like'%gre%';
```

- You need to use [inner join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)
- And do specify the condition in the where clause(`or` or `and`)